# Why does Python's PIL Image.draft( 'RGB', IMG_SIZE ) not work with joblib.Parallel()?

Tags: python, image, parallel-processing, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I want to fast load a huge amount of ~ 50k JPG-files with Python's PIL module.

```
    from joblib import Parallel, delayed
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np 

    IMG_SIZE = (224, 224)

    ################################################
    # version 1. does not work, but fast
    def load_images(filename):
      img = Image.open(filename)
      img.draft('RGB', IMG_SIZE) 
      img = np.asarray(img)
      return img

    ################################################
    # version 2. works, but slow
    def load_images(filename):
      img = Image.open(filename)
      img = np.asarray(img.resize(IMG_SIZE))
      return img

    images = Parallel( n_jobs = 10,
                       verbose=  5
                       )( delayed( load_images )( f )
                                              for f in df.filename )

    X = np.asarray(images)
    print(X.shape)
```

---

### Peformance observed :

```
    # 1. (50000,)             not ok 
    # 2. (50000, 224, 224, 3)     ok
```

Why is in case 1. the result not an array of rgb images?

Comment: What is `Parallel`? Why have you removed your `import` statements? Please put them back with [edit] so we know what modules you are using.

Comment: I added the moduls to the code, sorry!

Comment: I find your comment to version 1 very amusing.   "This does not work, but it is fast".  We could probably help with some even faster code that doesn't work, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q  :** *" Why is in case 1. the result not an array of rgb images? "*

Several candidates here.

The primary (documented) suspect is here :

```
                                                                             [docs]
    def draft(self, mode, size):
        """
        Configures the image file loader so it returns a version of the
        image that as closely as possible matches the given mode and
        size. For example, you can use this method to convert a color
        JPEG to greyscale while loading it.
        ...
        Note: This method is not implemented for most images. It is
        currently implemented only for JPEG and MPO images.
```

Given the documented behaviour and not knowing the original `filename`-referred original image-type & image-sizes, there seems to be the root cause in `.draft()`-method, not being implemented but for JPEG-s, has caused the PIL-by-design-deferred-to-act-ALAP image-reader --

> <sub>*" ... It is important to note that the library doesn’t decode or load the raster data unless it really has to. When you open a file, the file header is read to determine the file format and extract things like mode, size, and other properties required to decode the file, but the rest of the file is not processed until later.
>
>
> This means that opening an image file is a fast operation, which is independent of the file size and compression type. "*</sub>

-- to yield None or a "long"-bytefield or nothing at all, such as being observed in the `joblib.Parallel()`-caller-side collected 50k-long list-of-nothing.

```
>>> img.draft( 'RGB', IMG_SIZE )   # just sets internal ALAP-decoder attributes
>>> type( img )                    # show weak-typed variable type()
<class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
```

makes us totally dependent on whether `numpy.asarray()` "understands" the `PIL.*ImagePlugin.*ImageFile` sufficiently enough, to "consider" it be an "array-like" object and "knowing" a way, how to "excavate" the actual image-data out, into a wished to get `numpy.ndarray`-instance.

The above reported result `(50000,)`    shows us, `numpy` has failed on this assumption to "understand" that PIL-provided abstraction.

On the contrary, the `.resize()` method returns an `Image`-instance, that can be returned.

```
>>> print( img.resize.__doc__ )

        Returns a resized copy of this image.

              size: The requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple:
                    (width, height).

              resample: An optional resampling filter.
                        ...     
                        If omitted, or if the image has mode "1" or "P", it is
                        set `PIL.Image.NEAREST`.
              ...
       returns: An `~PIL.Image.Image` object.
```

---

### Interim remarks,
<sub>not relevant for an ultimate performance pipeline</sub>

Neither the original PIL nor the forked Pillow are known for their data-touching processing performance, they best serve for human-slow interactions ( as in prototyping ) and help us, humans, with serving as an abstraction-mediator layer, deferring any actual data-manipulation ( starting from reading data through actual file-I/O ) to take place ALAP, while providing meta-data early, so that setting up the image-processing pipeline "knows" `width`, `height`, `palette` and similar image meta-data beforehand.

This one is useful to indeed change the image data inplace and shall work here (not to return `None`-s, the inplace `.thumbnail()`-ed image data can next be made ready to actually be returned, using `.tobytes()` or similar PIL-native methods, that first start to actually move/return the internal data "through" a setup decoder to only finally yield some `return`-able data - `.transform()` being another one, but as a non-destructive data-"reporter", that can feed the `return` with new data itself ).

```
img.thumbnail( size     = IMG_SIZE,
               resample = Image.NEAREST
               ) # a documented in-place destructive transformer
return img.tobytes( ... )
```

The RAM ceiling is another suspect if striving for a production-grade code robustness - supposing all code-execution elements happen to work & return some reasonable value ( not only the thumbnail-re-sized, working, cases but perhaps also a side-effect caused full-sized originals, if `.draft()`-method, not implemented for other but JPEG-image-type, would cause the deferred `PIL.Image.reader` to actually "deliver" a full copy of the original-image-size ), the overall RAM-size footprint guesstimate is well above 120 GB for the working case 2), where just tiny-sized thumbnails get produced - as :

```
50E3 * 224 * 224 * 3 * 8 * 2 / 1E9      is 120.42 [GB]
```

( as having in-RAM both all the **`images`**-list & it's another replica, from `.asarray()`-method post-processed output, stored in `X[50000,224,224,3]`-of-64-bit numpy-default `dtype` data -- plus -- having spawned 10-full-copies of the `main`-Python-interpreter eco-system, with its full internal memory-state of the interpreter, with all imported modules, and all data-structures in all global and local variables -- including the pilot-tape `df.filename`, that governs the iterator responsible for scheduling the remote-processing in `n_jobs`-copies of itself, as trying to evade the Python-GIL-lock blocking -- replicated that many times, as `joblib.Parallel()` has produced )

---

### If striving for ultimate performance :

- numpy native image loader with vectorised using striding-tricks to apply "`PIL.Image.NEAREST`"
- pre-allocated storages of `X_i`-s, for block-orchestrated, yet incremental, best in-place storage of results, so as to keep RAM footprint less than half of the anti-pattern documented above ( 2x less RAM ... and 50k RAM-allocation avoided at all )
- explicitly control the `numpy.dtype`, not to let `numpy` reserve full 64-bit **`8 [B]`**-s to store just as few as 8-bits of the actual RGB-pieces of information ( 8x less RAM ... )

can all help improve the End-to-End processing pipeline-speed.

As the process is more memory-I/O intensive than anything else ( without knowing the original-image sizes, still the RGBA/RGB/? data processing during any type of the "down-scaling" filter-recalculations keeps to be memory-I/O intensive ), the number of `joblib.Parallel( n_jobs = ... )`-processes need not & most probably, if not using some indeed ultra-specific hardware fabric, not by any means common in 2022/Q1, will not improve the E2E-performance, as the memory-I/O will start blocking any wished to have positive impact of that many worker-processes, just waiting for a free physical memory-I/O channel.

If indeed in a dire need for performance, my tip would be to :

- fine-tune the balance of number of `n_jobs` worker-processing to be less than the amount of physical-memory-I/O-channels on your hardware
- pre-allocate numpy-storage `X_i[50000/n_jobs,224,224,3]` being `dtype = np.int8`
- avoid awfully many overhead costs of passing individual filenames 50000-times, but rather ask (now) a few-enough worker-processes to take their fair share from the 50k-files in `df.filename`-s ( they know about, as being "full-copies" of the whole Python-interpreter, don't they? ), so scripting the "expensive" iterator-loop internally at no overhead costs ( avoided iterator-costs, avoided SER/DES costs, avoided IPC-communication costs ), just by starting at offset of the `_i`-th block and taking all sub-block's filenames straight from the `df.filename` on-the-fly of the embarrasingly independent file-I/O and data-conversion
- returning a set of `X_i`-s ( best as just file-handles, not the full-data -- ref. the all avoidable `X_i`-th DATA-size ( already reduced from ~ **`60 [GB]`** to about `7.5 [GB]` being still a waste of resources to "pass-through" DATA-wise, instead of by-reference ) progressively growing { SER/DES + RAM-allocation + RAM-I/O + IPC-transport }-add-on-costs ) then permits to efficiently stack them together even for cases, that have grown beyond the physical RAM, using numpy to store `X_i`-th data rather in disk-files and use `numpy.memmap()`-s to assemble them all into a one, "beyond-RAM"-sized `numpy.ndarray`
- switching off verbosity is another self-evident performance booster